# Blank screen after using react <Provider>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to make a webpage using React js and use redux template. I am trying to wrap my component around < Provider >. After wrapping i get a blank page. I tried using React developer tools that too appears blank. here is my code. I have tried different methods nut none of them works.

Main.js

```
import Title from './Title'
import Photowall from './Photowall'
import AddPhoto from './AddPhoto'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
class Main extends Component{

constructor(){
    super()
    this.state= {
        posts : [{
            id: "0",
            description: "beautiful landscape",
            imageLink: "https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/none/path/sa6549607c78f5c11/image/i4eeacaa2dbf12d6d/version/1490299332/most-beautiful-landscapes-in-europe-lofoten-european-best-destinations-copyright-iakov-kalinin.jpg" +
            "3919321_1443393332_n.jpg"
            }, {
            id: "1",
            description: "Aliens???",
            imageLink: "https://s3.india.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/rocket.jpg"
            }, {
            id: "2",
            description: "On a vacation!",
            imageLink: "https://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2017/08/24/104670887-VacationExplainsTHUMBWEB.1910x1000.jpg"
            }],
          
        }
        this.removePhoto=this.removePhoto.bind(this)
        }

    removePhoto(postRemoved){
        console.log(postRemoved.description)
       this.setState((state) => ({
            posts: state.posts.filter(post => post !== postRemoved)
          }))
    }

    addPhoto(postSubmitted){
        this.setState(state => ({
            posts:state.posts.concat([postSubmitted])
        }))
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
        console.log(prevState.posts)
        console.log(this.state)
    }
render() {        
    return (

    <div> 
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
            <div>
                <Title title={'Photowall'}/>
                <Photowall posts={this.state.posts} onRemovePhoto={this.removePhoto} onNavigate={this.navigate}/>
             </div>
       
       )}/>
     
      <Route path="/AddPhoto" render={({history})=>(
         <AddPhoto onAddPhoto={(addedPost)=>{
             this.addPhoto(addedPost)
            history.push('/')
         }}/>
        )}/>
          </div>

    )
    }
    }    
export default Main
```

AddPhoto.js

```
 import React, { Component } from "react"

 class AddPhoto extends Component{
   constructor(){
    super()
    this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}
 
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const imageLink = event.target.elements.link.value
    const description = event.target.elements.description.value
    const post = {
        id:0,
        description:description,
        imageLink:imageLink          
    }
    if(description && imageLink){
        this.props.onAddPhoto(post)
    }
 }

 render(){
    return(
    <div>
         <h1>Photowall</h1>
        <div className="form">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Link" name="link"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Description" name="description"/>
            <button>Post</button>
        
        </form>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    )
   }
   }

   export default AddPhoto
```

Photo.js

```
 import React, {Component} from "react";
 import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
 function Photo(props){
    const post =props.post
     return <figure className="figure">
                 <img className="photo" src={post.imageLink} alt={post.description}/>
                 <figcaption><p>{post.description}</p></figcaption>
                 <div className="button-container">
                 <button className="remove-button" onClick={()=>{ 
                    props.onRemovePhoto(post);
                }}> Remove </button>
                 </div>
          </figure>

      }

      Photo.propTypes={
      post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      onRemovePhoto:PropTypes.func.isRequired
      }
      export default Photo
```

Photowall.js

```
 import React,{ Component} from 'react'
 import Photo from './Photo'
 import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
 import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
 function Photowall(props){
    return <div>
        <Link className='addIcon' to='/AddPhoto' ><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0Ij48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTIgMGMtNi42MjcgMC0xMiA1LjM3My0xMiAxMnM1LjM3MyAxMiAxMiAxMiAxMi01LjM3MyAxMi0xMi01LjM3My0xMi0xMi0xMnptNyAxNGgtNXY1aC00di01aC01di00aDV2LTVoNHY1aDV2NHoiLz48L3N2Zz4="></img> </Link>
        {/*<button onClick={props.onNavigate} className='addIcon'> + </button>*/}
           <div className='photo-grid'>
            {props.posts.map((post, index) => <Photo key={index} post={post} onRemovePhoto={props.onRemovePhoto}/>)}
           </div>
           </div>
     }
     Photowall.propTypes={
     posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
     onRemovePhoto:PropTypes.func.isRequired
     }
     export default Photowall
```

index.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import Main from './Components/Main'
 import './styles/stylesheet.css'
 import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
 import {createStore} from 'redux'
 import rootReducer from './redux/reducer'
 import {Provider} from "react-redux";
 const store = createStore(rootReducer)



 ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><BrowserRouter><Main/></BrowserRouter></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

reducer.js

```
import posts from '../data/posts'

const postReducer = function posts(state = posts,action){
return state

}

export default postReducer
```

Comment: A completely blank screen would usually be accompanied by a console error, is there anything in the console?

Comment: None of your components seem to be connected to the redux store? There should be a part in the tutorial/template you followed where either `connect()` or `useSelector` and `useDispatch` is used. Btw if this is a new codebase (not some legacy project you have to maintain), I'd recommend to check out redux-toolkit. A lot of boilerplate code that used to be necessary to set up react+redux has disappeared, it's much more enjoyable.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am getting this error:  Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.
    at createStore (createStore.js:55:1)
    at ./src/index.js (index.js:8:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1

Comment: How do i Resolve this error?